# New to Jython Need help extracting data from file

Tags: jython, wsadmin

I am new to scripting and programing in general.  I am trying to run WebSphere command line tool, wsadmin, and it keeps failing. I am looking for answers for 2 questions about the following code:

---

```
**import sys
import os
import re
execfile('wsadminlib.py')
appName = sys.argv[1]
configLocation = "/location/of/config/"
config_prop = open(configLocation + appName+"-Config.csv", "r")

for line in config_prop:
    line = line.split(",")
    print line**
```

---

I launch run the scripts in as wsadmin and from the command line is as follows:

```
>>>>./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f deploy.sh param1
```

Questions:

1. The problem is that it fails on the "for line in config_prop" with AttributeError: **getitem**?
2. when I run this through python on the same machine, the code works.  Just not when I run it through wsadmin tool?
3. Is there other ways to extract data from txt or csv with comma delimited and setting a variable for each word that is only one line long.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. the libraries used is 2.1 and the syntax i was using was post 2.2.